# iOS/Swift - If/ if else statement not working as it should

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been trying to get this code to work for the past few hours. But I have been getting mixed results.

```
 static func uploadDataToServer(data: Data, secondData: Data? = nil, thirdData: Data? = nil, firstVideoURL: URL? = nil, secondVideoURL: URL? = nil, thirdVideoURL: URL? = nil, caption: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL {
        SingleVideoHandler.uploadOneVideoToFirebase(firstVideoURL: firstVideoURL, onSuccess: { (vidURL) in
            uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage(data: data, secondData: secondData!, thirdData: thirdData!, onSuccess: { (firstImage, secondImage, thirdImage) in
                sendDataToDatabase(firstPhotoURL: firstImage, secondPhotoURL: secondImage, thirdPhotoURL: thirdImage ,firstVideoURL: vidURL, caption: caption, onSuccess: onSuccess)

                })
        })
    } else {


    if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL, let secondVideoURL = secondVideoURL {
    print("Got two pics!")
        MultipleVideoHandler.uploadTwoVideosToFirebase(firstVideoURL: firstVideoURL, secondVideoURL: secondVideoURL, onSuccess: { (firstVidURL, secondVidURL) in
            uploadImagesToFirebaseStorage(data: data, secondData: secondData!, thirdData: thirdData!, onSuccess: { (firstImage, secondImage, thirdImage) in
                sendDataToDatabase(firstPhotoURL: firstImage, secondPhotoURL: secondImage, thirdPhotoURL:  thirdImage, firstVideoURL: firstVidURL, secondVideoURL: secondVidURL, caption: caption, onSuccess: onSuccess)

            })
        })
    } else {
          if let secondImageData = secondData, let thirdImageData = thirdData {
            uploadThreeImagesToFirebaseStorage(data: data, secondData: secondImageData, thirdData: thirdImageData) { (firstPhotoURL, secondPhotoURL, thirdPhotoURL) in
                self.sendDataToDatabase(firstPhotoURL: firstPhotoURL, secondPhotoURL: secondPhotoURL, thirdPhotoURL: thirdPhotoURL, caption: caption, onSuccess: onSuccess)
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to detect wether I have a `firstVideoURL`, a `secondVideoURL` and a `thirdVideoURL`.

However, in order to have a `secondVideoURL` you must have a `firstVideoURL`. Like wise with regards to having a `thirdVideoURL` you must have both a `firstVideoURL` and a `secondVideoURL`.

What I'm doing in essence it allowing for optional videos, where users can select up to three videos to upload and images. Only have 3 parameters as of now, due to to testing.

I'm trying to detect how many videoURLs I have, and based of that, upload however many videos have been selected and additional content.

My results so far:

Only the first `if-let` statement is called and executed. Even thought I have more than one videoURL.

The code is called multiple times, creating the same instance of a post, however, the first instance will only contain the firstVideoURL and the second instance will have both the first and second video URL. The second instance is what I want. But I do not want the first instance.

I cannot figure out as to why this is happening?

Could someone please help me out?

Thank you.

In essence this is what I want-

I've got 2 video URL
The code is executed
Checks the conditions
Skips the first `if-let statement`
Executes the second `if-let statement`.

In terms of uploading and create posts, the server/api code works as expected. Just this conditional operation is not working as I anticipated.

Comment: What stops you from using an array containing `URL?`? You can filter out the nils

Comment: @CodeDifferent Using Firebase. Doesn't allow bulk uploads/downloads. But I just don't understand as to why anything below the first if-let statement isn't called.

Comment: The way you coded it, if the first URL is not nil, it will only upload that, and nothing else. Code it in reverse: if all 3 are available, upload all 3; else if two of them are available, upload two; else if one is available, upload it

Comment: Still make for a very messy solution. Better rewrite your Firebase uploader

Comment: @CodeDifferent Haha, at this rate, I'll take anything. I appreciate it, thank you. I'll let you know the result(s).

Comment: @CodeDifferent Tried to use a switch statement, but no matter what I did would refuse to compile succesfully.

Comment: @CodeDifferent    Code works for 1 video as well as 2, when I upload 3 videos, 3 instances are created. Edit - Just used a return statement. Fixed the issue.

Comment: ?? Why do you need a separate function per number of videos being uploaded? What if you need 4, 5? 100? You're going to make a separate function for each? Make just one which takes an array of any number of images to uload

Comment: @Alexander I've only permitted 3, this was for purely eligibility of my code.

Comment: "eligibility"??? What's eligible about needing to modify three separate functions when a single behaviour change is desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first if condition (if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL) passes if there's firstVideoURL, it doesn't care about secondVideoURL and/or thirdVideoURL. If thats what you need you should consider constructing your if-else like below:

```
if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL{
   if let secondVideoURL = secondVideoURL{
      if let thirdVideoURL = thirdVideoURL{
         //Do what you would if there are all the three video urls.
      } else {
         //Do what you would if there are firstVideoURL and secondVideoURL but not the thirdVideoURL
      }
   } else {
      //Do what you would if there is only the firstVideoURL
   }
} else {
     //Handle the case when there are no video urls.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to allow it to be called with NO video URLS? If so, why? You've made all 3 videoURL parameters optional, which doesn't seem to make sense. It seems to me that you should allow one, 2, or 3.

In any case, your code doesn't make sense as written. Once the first if clause fails, you know that firstVideoURL is nil, so the second if clause is also going to fail.

If you're going to continue with this approach, I think @CodeDifferent has the right idea with their comment:

```
if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL, 
  let secondVideoURL = secondVideoURL,
  let thirdVideoURL = thirdVideoURL {
    //upload 3 videos
} else if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL, 
  let secondVideoURL = secondVideoURL {
    //upload 2 videos
} else if let firstVideoURL = firstVideoURL {
    //upload 1 video 
} else {
    //No videos. Why is this possible?
}
```

(I don't really understand your use of both video URLs and data objects, so I ignored that part.)

However, lets take a step back. Why are you using 3 separate sets of optional parameters and dealing with a messy construct of `if let` optional bindings? Why not pass in an array of video URLS?

```
func uploadDataToServer( data: [Data], urls: [URL]) {
  //Loop through the array of data objects/URLs and upload each one.
}
```

Comment: First one will never fail. I just tested it. If a user selects an image and then selects a video, tapping the second image view. The video is then slotted into the firstImageView which equals firstVideoURL.

Comment: Again, having multiple methods and special cases for different numbers of images is messy and awkward. Use arrays.

Comment: @Dunac C I read Firebase don't allow bulk uploads/downloads. Hence why I resorted to this.